# Windows 8 and SMB2 Issues

Tags: windows, network-share, server-message-block, windows-8

We're playing with the consumer preview of Windows 8 and having issues accessing some network shares in our environment.

Basically, when I attempt to access a share directly (\[SERVER].[DOMAIN].[NETWORK]\Share$) I get 'An extended error has occured'.

The shares reside on an EMC Celerra system. Sorry, I don't really have much more information about it (this is just a little side project). Accessing shares that reside on Windows machines are fine.

The Firewall is completley disabled and I am running under full domain administrative credentials.

A quick wireshark shows the following group of packets between myself and the server:

```
SMB2    164 NegotiateProtocol Request
SMB2    274 NegotiateProtocol Response
SMB2    981 SessionSetup Request
SMB2    281 SessionSetup Response
SMB2    200 TreeConnect Request Tree: \\[SERVER].[DOMAIN].[NETWORK]\[SHARE]$
SMB2    138 TreeConnect Response
SMB2    202 Ioctl Request NETWORK_FILE_SYSTEM Function:0x0080
SMB2    131 Ioctl Response, Error: STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST
SMB2    126 SessionLogoff Request
SMB2    126 SessionLogoff Respons
```

This repeats five times and then (I assume) Windows throws me the above error.

A quick Google shows me:

```
0xC0000010
STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST
The specified request is not a valid operation for the target device.
```

Which shows me that NETWORK_FILE_SYSTEM Function:0x0080 request is invalid..

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Thanks in advance.

Rhys.

**Edit**: FYI - as a workaround, you can disable SMB 2.2 as noted in the EMC thread:

```
sc config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi
sc config mrxsmb20 start= disabled
```

This will allow the machine to access the shares. The below answer still stands though :)

Comment: Wow. Is this SF's first [Window 8] compatible question?

Comment: @jscott: Probably, if "What the @#%$^!!" doesn't count as a question.

Comment: @jscott We had one when the Dev preview came out, but it got shuffled elsewhere as I recall.

Comment: pretty sure that all you get out of the latest celerra release is a clean smb2.0 client without support for 2.2.

Comment: @tonyroth Which if it makes W8 work, would make sense. If W8 is using some obscure SMB2.0 functions that W7 didn't use, I can totally see that breaking things for non-Microsoft SMB stacks.

Comment: it will be awhile before any of the 3rd party devices will support smb2.2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know the specific cause, it appears that the problem [has already been noted in EMC circles](https://community.emc.com/message/595827). According to them, you'll need the newest Celerra release you can get your hands on.

I suspect the core of the problem is that Windows 8 uses SMB2.2, and one of two things is happening:

1. Celerra isn't fully implementing the protocol it negotiates with the Win8 box.
2. Protocol negotiation is failing to come to a correct agreement; perhaps it's suggesting it can do SMB2.2, when in fact it can't and is caught out later.

Comment: Thanks mate, you were correct. We are running a slightly older version of Celerra which, looking at that thread on the EMC forums, appears to be the cause. Appreciate your assistance everyone.

Comment: Another workaround worth trying is to disable Secure Dialect Negotiation. This will allow you to use SMB2.1 but leave you vulnerable to an SMB1 downgrade. Set this DWORD `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\RequireSecureNegotiate=2`